# can't return nested called outlook function

Tags: javascript

I have an outlook javascript function where I am trying to get the value of `MyMessage` into the console.log outside of the full function, however I am having trouble.

```
function confirmedsendheaders() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(function (asyncResult) {
     if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
     MyMessage = `Hello Support, <br>
<br>
This is an automated email from` + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName + ` to check if this is spam. <br>
<br>      
<b>Email Header Information: </b>
<br>
`+ asyncResult.value
      return MyMessage

    }

  })
}
```

I also tried putting the return right next to the variable in question but no luck:

```
function confirmedsendheaders() {
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(function (asyncResult) {
     if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
     return MyMessage = `Hello Support, <br>
<br>
This is an automated email from` + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName + ` to check if this is spam. <br>
<br>
<b>Email Header Information: </b>
<br>
`+ asyncResult.value
      

    }

  })
}
```

I read this: [Return value from nested function in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611980/return-value-from-nested-function-in-javascript) and it mentions that the second function needs to be called, but it looks like it gets called at the beginning unless I am wrong. Any ideas?

Edit: I also tried to have a variable equal the same result from the nested function to see if that work but no luck. I saw the idea from this post:https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373953

third attempt:

```
function confirmedsendheaders() {
var secret = ''
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(function (asyncResult) {
     if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
     MyMessage = `Hello Support, <br>
<br>
This is an automated email from` + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName + ` to check if this is spam. <br>
<br>
<b>Email Header Information: </b>
<br>
`+ asyncResult.value
      secret = MyMessage.secret

    }

  })
return secret
}
```

This is not a async function. I tried to add await and it said: `Uncaught SyntaxError: **await is only valid in async** functions and the top level bodies of modules`
Fourth attempt

```
function confirmedsendheaders() {
var secret = ''
  Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(function (asyncResult) {
     var secret = await if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
     MyMessage = `Hello Support, <br>
<br>
This is an automated email from` + Office.context.mailbox.userProfile.displayName + ` to check if this is spam. <br>
<br>
<b>Email Header Information: </b>
<br>
`+ asyncResult.value
    }

  })
return secret
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that issue. Turns out that `Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync` is asynchronus but it looks different than a normal async function. I tried multiple ways of trying to await for the value but the console.log kept saying that await would only work with an async function which made me belive taht `Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync` wasn't asynchronus even though its in the name.

After reading this post here that explain more about Office apps functions, I was able to guess enough times to get it right: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491150

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.getAllInternetHeadersAsync(async function (asyncResult){})
```